# Handling Population within a game (unity)

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a sim city style game, and I am currently looking into managing the population for the city. The script will eventually work as when a house is placed, that house adds to the capacity of how many people the city can house. When the construction is complete then I will add that number of citizen structs to a List of citizens.

However, imagine that the population reaches in excess of 1000, 10000 citizens. Will this be the optimal solution for controlling a large volume of citizens? Moreover, when a house is removed this will remove the amount for the population (removing from the list) thus leaving job vacancies. I eventually would like for the player to be able to shift focus so any buildings with enum category of the focus shift will mean the work force will fill in those jobs first. Again would using the List and Linq queries be the way to go or would there be a better solution found with something else?

```
public class City : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Citizen> citizens = new List<Citizen>();
    public List<Building> cityBuildings = new List<Building>();

    // TODO (LINQ): Method for checking if a building has no employees and this employee is unemployed then assign this citizen to the building
}

public struct Citizen
{
    public Building employedAt;

    public bool CheckEmployment()
    {
        if (employedAt != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `List.Add()` and `List.Remove()` are pretty fast operations. I don't see a performance problem here.

Comment: You shouldn't use `struct` here at all but `class`! Otherwise e.g. your `Building` in the list is in no matter connected to the `employedAt` in the `Citizen`! `struct` is a value type so you would have independent copies with the same value. What you rather want are `class`es so any change in a `Building` is automatically also reflected in the `employedAt` of all according citizens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is - as you may have expected - it depends. The LINQ-operations are usually quite fast unless you are talking millions of objects. However they will produce some garbage that has to be collected eventually. If you perform such operations every frame you may run into GC hiccups. If you run stuff not that often (e.g. only when a player places/removes a house, etc.) this approach should work fine.

If you need maximum performance you may want to have a look at the new DOTS architecture (aka. ECS) in Unity, which allows you to manage large quantities of data fast. That being said - premature optimization is the root of all evil and DOTS is quite the beast to wrap your head around.

I'd start with the LINQ queries, making sure they are not called every frame and maybe some clever caching and only bring in the big guns when I actually have a performance problem.

Comment: Brilliant! I have looked into ECS but I am staying clear at the moment because I still have a lot to learn regarding most c# principles, but this is good to know for future development. Thank you for your time

Comment: Note that regarding LINQ Microsoft themselves actually recommends in their [Performance recommendations for Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/mixed-reality/performance-recommendations-for-unity#cpu-performance-recommendations): **Avoid use of LINQ**

Comment: That may be true for certain use cases (e.g. LINQ in tight loops) but I think that such blanket statements have to be taken with a grain of salt. Code readability and maintainability almost always wins over performance concerns. If your profiling shows that you have performance issues with a certain LINQ statement then by all means expand it out to some manual code (if you use the Rider IDE you can basically let the IDE do that for you). Other than that I suggest you keep the LINQ as it is more readable and maintainable.